# Income vs Earnings

Tags: word-choice, differences, vocabulary

I was looking for a synonym for the word "income", and then I came across the word "earnings". Do these two words have the same meaning? Are they interchangeable in the following sentence?

> In conclusion, I strongly agree that the modern society emphasizes more in professional obligations than in personal enjoyment. This is because there is more competition in the working places and because individuals need to work more in order to increase their **earnings**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here [earnings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/earnings) is synonymous with [income](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/income) and means:

> the amount of money that someone is paid for working:
>
> - Average earnings for skilled workers are rising.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I don't see how your pasted definition supports your assertion that _income_ and _earnings_ are synonymous. "Income" can include moneys gained from investments, gambling winnings, bank interest, sale of property, etc. – and one of your links even says this.

Comment: @J.R. - the sense is, as per OP request, that earnings and income can be used interchangeably in the sentence above. I agree that income has a wider meaning, but it would fit and convey the correct meaning  here.

Comment: I would think a more useful answer, then, would not merely focus on a trivial example where they are synonymous, but also discuss how they are different.

Comment: @J.R. - in what way does it not answer the question?. It clearly states “***here*** earnings is synonymous with income”.

Comment: I see two questions, not one. The first is, "Do these two words have the same meaning?" I don't think you've done a good job answering that. In any case, I didn't want to get in a debate; I was merely giving a suggestion on how your answer could be improved. If you think it's fine, leave it be. (P.S. ***here*** meaning, "Here in the following Cambridge Dictionary quote, or meaning, "Up there in the original sentence you've quoted"?)

Comment: You've given the definition of 'earnings'. What about 'income'? There are also things that dictionaries don't give, like frequency, collocations, regional preference, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do these words have the same meaning? They are related but there is a subtle difference: income is the umbrella term and earnings refer to your salary or wage. Other possible income sources could be rents from property, share dividends, interest on savings.
Can they be used here in this context interchangeably? Yes, I would say so.